# Do certain characters need to be escaped to be searchable in vim?

Tags: search, vim, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having what seems to me bizarre behavior with vim search functionality. As far as I can tell the problem is only with capital 'W'. Typing this character in the search bar as

```
/W
```

will instantly expand to

```
/w ^I^I^I^I^I^I
```

preventing me from finding any instances of 'W'. The same happens if I try a search and replace. Typing 'W' in command mode will degrade to the 'w ^I^I^I^I^I^I' string without me doing anything.

I was wondering if 'W' is some sort of special character I need to escape or something. I don't see why it would be though, because I don't get this behavior on other computers. Just on my Ubuntu 12.04. Any solutions or input are appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm that `/W` works correctly for me with no special behaviour.  I am unsure what your bug is however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a command-line mapping for `W`.

```
:verbose cmap W
```

will tell you and where it is defined.

If you want to alias commands, you need to use a more refined mapping that only applies at the beginning of the command-line, or use a plugin like [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746).

Comment: Thank you! That's what I get for using someone else's vimrc file. I commented out all the cmaps and it's working now.